# Are GAMMs/GLM the best choice for calculating number of germs on hands?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, multilevel-analysis

We would like your opinion on whether GAMMs are a good option and how best to go about implementing for the following:

During a period of patient care, a nurse will accrue $Y$ colonies of bacteria on their hands. During every hand contact ($n$) (with surface area $A$) with a surface this number may increase a percentage ($\lambda$ %) of what she touches ($V$). However potentially this may also decrease as some percentage ($\beta$ %) of the bacteria are removed. After they finish the care episode, they may wash their hands with efficacy $h$.

The model is hence dependent on $Y=Y(n,A,V,\lambda,\beta,h)$

**We think:**

> $n$=empirical, different for every nurse, $h=lognormal~(1.5,0.1)$, $\lambda=\Gamma(15,3)$, $\beta=$empirical non-negative.
>   $A=lognormal~(7,1.9)$ and $V$=empirical, $h=\Gamma(5.91,0.4)$.

We'd like to know if GAM fitting is an appropriate way of estimating $Y$. Please let us know if you require further clarification.

Regards,

Comment: I'm a little confused -- you you have data on all of your explanatory variables?  It seems like not, if you're specifying a distribution for them.  Or are you doing something Bayesian, and sampling from a multivariate prior?  If so, do your unobserved variables correlate with each other, or with your observed variables?

Comment: @ACD The only known input variables are $n$ (the number of surfaces each nurse touches) and $V$ (the contamination level of the surfaces). During each surface contact $\lambda$,$A$, and $\beta$ vary according to the given distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the model is incomplete.  Why not consider her hands as a forest of SIR models?  There are some things that "die on the vine" and for that "R" applies.

Here are links on SIR:

- http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/loci/joma/the-sir-model-for-spread-of-disease-the-differential-equation-model
- http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v44/issue_2/IJAM_44_2_06.pdf
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemic_model

It seems that lognormal distributions may apply to some limited set of special cases of disease, but they are not general enough for unilateral applicability.

I have my head in random forests and a forest of SIR models (see IJAM link) is going to account for variation, give you robust answers, and have a basis that is generally applicable to the problem.